# Change language for bootstrap DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, translate, smalot-datetimepicker

I use `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` Copyright 2012 by Stefan Petre

http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.php

I import the js and another language, for example Russian:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="/Resources/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="/Resources/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.ru.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

in document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // debugger;

    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
        isRTL: false,
        format: 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii',
        autoclose:true
    });
});
```

but it is not translated

I tried to insert on init

```
**language: "RU"**
**language: "ru"**
**language: "ru-RU"**
```

but nothing changes, 
Do you have any proposal?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

i think you have to set it in the options:

```
$(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
    isRTL: false,
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii',
    autoclose:true,
    language: 'ru'
});
```

if its not working, be sure that:

```
$.fn.datetimepicker.dates['en'] = {
    days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
    daysShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
    daysMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
    months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    today: "Today"
};
```

is defined for 'ru'

Comment: when I include language file I get error that $.fn.datetimepicker.dates is undefined...

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki if you copied the OPs code he included a library of when he last ate (atetimepicker) and not the datetimepicker.

Comment: @Lee Winter I've read your comment ten times and I still don't understand it.

Comment: @ViktorJoras I think the code originally had a typo missing the d off datetimepicker and has since been corrected

Comment: Useless. `Cannot set property 'en' of undefined`

Answer (score 22):

If you use **`moment.js`** the you need to load `moment-with-locales.min.js` not `moment.min.js`. Otherwise, your `locale: 'ru'` will not work.

Comment: What is moment.js? There is no mention of any moment.js in the OPs code.

Comment: @ViktorJoras if you look at requirements for using this plugin then you will see that current plugin require use mommen.js library.

Please look at [plugin site](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/)

If you have any questions please ask

Answer (score 18):

you need to add the javascript language file,after the  moment library, example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment/es.js"></script>
```

now you can set a language.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({locale:'es'});
});
</script>
```

Here are all language: https://github.com/moment/moment

Comment: You can also use moment-with-locale and include all the locales under a sub-directory called locale relative to the moment.js file

Comment: if it is also possible.

Answer (score 11):

The option is `locale: 'ru'`

But first, you have to call the script `../moment.js/version/locale/ru.js`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

Just include your desired locale after the plugin. You can find it in **locales** folder on github https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/tree/master/dist/locales

```
<script src="bootstrap-datepicker.XX.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

and then add option

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
   language: 'XX'
});
```

Where **XX** is your desired locale like **ru**

Comment: This is the best answer for me.

Comment: This should be accepted answer. No include moment js or whatsoever. Just simple solution yet powerfull.

Answer (score 5):

1.you will use different locale array element in datepicker.js from following link
https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/tree/master/js/locales

2.add array in datepicker.js like this:

```js
$.fn.datepicker.Constructor = Datepicker;
    var dates = $.fn.datepicker.dates = {
        en: {
            days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"],
            daysShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
            daysMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
            months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
            monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            today: "Today"
        },
        CN:{
        days: ["星期日", "星期一", "星期二", "星期三", "星期四", "星期五", "星期六", "星期日"],
        daysShort: ["周日", "周一", "周二", "周三", "周四", "周五", "周六", "周日"],
    daysMin: ["日", "一", "二", "三", "四", "五", "六", "日"],
    months: ["一月", "二月", "三月", "四月", "五月", "六月", "七月", "八月", "九月", "十月", "十一月", "十二月"],
    monthsShort: ["一月", "二月", "三月", "四月", "五月", "六月", "七月", "八月", "九月", "十月", "十一月", "十二月"],
    today: "今天",
    suffix: [],
    meridiem: ["上午", "下午"]
}
 };
```

Answer (score 5):

1.First add this js file to your HTML.

```
<script th:src="@{${webLinkFactory.jsLibRootPath()}+'/bootstrap-datepicker.nl.min.js'}" charset="UTF-8"type="text/javascript"></script>
```

obviously after moment.min.js.

content of bootstrap-datepicker.nl.min.js will be

```
;(function($){
    $.fn.datepicker.dates['nl'] = {
        days: ["Zondag", "Maandag", "Dinsdag", "Woensdag", "Donderdag", "Vrijdag", "Zaterdag", "Zondag"],
        daysShort: ["Zon", "Man", "Din", "Woe", "Don", "Vri", "Zat", "Zon"],
        daysMin: ["Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za", "Zo"],
        months: ["Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"],
        monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mrt", "Apr", "Mei", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"],
        today: "Vandaag",
        suffix: [],
        meridiem: []
    };
    $.fn.datetimepicker.dates['nl'] = {
        days: ["Zondag", "Maandag", "Dinsdag", "Woensdag", "Donderdag", "Vrijdag", "Zaterdag", "Zondag"],
        daysShort: ["Zon", "Man", "Din", "Woe", "Don", "Vri", "Zat", "Zon"],
        daysMin: ["Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za", "Zo"],
        months: ["Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"],
        monthsShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mrt", "Apr", "Mei", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"],
        today: "Vandaag",
        suffix: [],
        meridiem: []
    };
}(jQuery));
```

2.set this line in the ready function of your js file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.datetimepicker.defaults.language = 'nl';
}
```

3.initialize your datetimepicker in this way

```
$(this).datetimepicker({
                        format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii",
                        autoclose: true,
                        weekStart: 1,
                        locale: 'nl',
                        language: 'nl'
                    });
```

following this steps i was able to convert my english datepicker and datetimepicker to dutch successfully.

Answer (score 2):

all you are right! other way to getting !

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.ru.min.js
```

You can find out all languages on there https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datepicker

https://labs.maarch.org/maarch/maarchRM/commit/3299d1e7ed25018b48715e16a42d52c288b4da3e

Answer (score 1):

For those who like me could not solve this problem with the solutions above, I sugest verifying if you initialize the $(element).datetimepicker(...) in different locations at the same time.

In my case, after a long time, I found a global.js interfering with another datetimepicker initialization.

If you need for some reason maintain work with different initializations, in different files, remember to remove the datetimepicker before each one with:

`$(element).datetimepicker('remove')`

Reference: https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.php#methods

Edit: This solution still needs to import the language files correctly, right after the `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js`.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

for french speaker, this how you do it

```
        ;(function($){
        $.fn.datepicker.dates['fr'] = {
            days: ["dimanche", "lundi", "mardi", "mercredi", "jeudi", "vendredi", "samedi"],
            daysShort: ["dim.", "lun.", "mar.", "mer.", "jeu.", "ven.", "sam."],
            daysMin: ["d", "l", "ma", "me", "j", "v", "s"],
            months: ["janvier", "février", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin", "juillet", "août", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "décembre"],
            monthsShort: ["janv.", "févr.", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin", "juil.", "août", "sept.", "oct.", "nov.", "déc."],
            today: "Aujourd'hui",
            monthsTitle: "Mois",
            clear: "Effacer",
            weekStart: 1,
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        };
    }(jQuery));

    $('.js-datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        startDate: new Date(),
        language: 'fr',
    });
```

thx to this source from : https://www.1formatik.com/1056/comment-mettre-bootstrap-datepicker-en-francais

Answer (score 0):

This is for your reference only:

https://github.com/rajit/bootstrap3-datepicker/tree/master/locales/zh-CN

https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.1/i18n.html

The case is as follows：

```
 <div class="input" id="event_period">
   <input class="date" required="required" type="text">
 </div>

 $.fn.datepicker.dates['zh-CN'] = {
    days:["星期日","星期一","星期二","星期三","星期四","星期五","星期六"],
    daysShort:["周日","周一","周二","周三","周四","周五","周六"],
    daysMin:["日","一","二","三","四","五","六"],
    months:["一月","二月","三月","四月","五月","六月","七月","八月","九月","十月","十一月","十二月"],
    monthsShort:["1月","2月","3月","4月","5月","6月","7月","8月","9月","10月","11月","12月"],
    today:"今日",
    clear:"清除"
  };

  $('#event_period').datepicker({
    inputs: $('input.date'),
    todayBtn: "linked",
    clearBtn: true,
    format: "yyyy年mm月",
    titleFormat: "yyyy年mm月",
    language: 'zh-CN',
    weekStart:1 // Available or not
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( ".form_datetime" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "zh-CN" ], { dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii' });
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying out the most of the solutions I always got `Cannot set property 'en' of undefined` error, and couldn't get localization to work.

The solution for me was that I have to upgrade `bootstrap-datetimepicker` to 4.0.0 or newer version, and include `moment-with-locales.js` before it.

```
<script src="{{asset('js/theme/moment-with-locales.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/theme/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js')}}"></script>


$('#program_start_date').datetimepicker({
  useCurrent: false,
  icons: {
    time: 'far fa-clock',
    up: 'fas fa-chevron-up',
    down: 'fas fa-chevron-down',
    previous: 'fas fa-chevron-left',
    next: 'fas fa-chevron-right',
  },
  locale : 'hu'                                          
});
```