# bootstrap-datepicker set language globally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using [bootstrap-datepaginator](http://jondmiles.com/bootstrap-datepaginator/) that inside uses bootstrap-datepicker. 
Utilizzanto bootstrap-datepicker as a single component, there are no problems to set the language, but the same is not true using bootstrap-datepaginator. How can I do?

I'm trying to set the Italian language as a default for the entire project. 
In `index.html` I put the following script:

```
<script src="vendors/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/jquery-ui/ui/i18n/datepicker-it.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "it" ] );
    });
</script>
```

But in the console I get these errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'regional' of undefined datepicker-it.js:15
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'regional' of undefined (index):394
```

I tried everything but I'm going crazy!

[Bootstrap Datepicker i18n](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/i18n.html)

---

I changed the code in this way:

```
<script src="vendors/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/bootstrap-datepicker/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.it.js"></script>


<script>
    $(function() {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional["it"] );
    });
</script>
```

but now the error is as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDefaults' of undefined
```

---

With this fix:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    language: "it"
});
```

I haven't got errors in console but the language is always english by default

Comment: I think you are missing an include for the jQuery UI datepicker - you only include the localized content for it.

Comment: You're using the bootstrap datepicker, not the jQueryUI one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382189/change-language-for-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can set default options for Bootstrap Datepicker by assigning them like so:

```
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.language = 'it';
```

Example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.fn.datepicker.defaults.language = 'it';
});

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.datepicker-fork/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.datepicker-fork/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.datepicker-fork/1.3.0/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.it.js"></script>
<input class="datepicker"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @mccannf!! You have found the solution to my problem !!

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery's extend() utility method to merge your settings into the datepicker defaults object:

```
$.extend( $.fn.datepicker.defaults, {format: 'dd-mm-yyyy', language: 'nl'} );
```

Comment: That has fixed for me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="/jquery/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jquery/jquery.ui.datepicker-it.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional["it"] );

$( "#data" ).datepicker();
</script>
```

Comment: If I try to do as you say I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDefaults' of undefined

Comment: See Rory comment.. i'm not using jquery datepicker but bootstrap -.-