# Bootstrap-datepicker set language

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using Bootstrap datepicker and I tried to change the language value with a variable content but it doesn't take it . 
I found a question already asked about this that seems like my problem , i did all the solutions given but doesn't work neither. Actually it's always in the default language "en".

this is the question 
[bootstrap-datepicker set language globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487765/bootstrap-datepicker-set-language-globally)

this is a part of my code in jquery

```
            var atrLang= $('.datepicker').attr('data-lang');
            //this retrn "langFr" for exemple 
            var langUp= (atrLang.slice(atrLang.length -2)).toLowerCase();
            //this return "fr"
            //i tried to change the default language like this
            //$.extend( $.fn.datepicker.defaults, {format: 'dd-mm-yyyy', language: langUp} );
             //it return an error "typeError: dates[this.o.language] is undefined"

            $('#datepicker_drop_off').datepicker({
              todayHighlight: true,
              weekStart: 1,
              startDate: new Date(),
              //add the current language to the language of the calendar
              language: langUp,
          })
```

I hope you can help me. 
Thanks

Comment: Check this topic i hope it helps you [DateTimePicker Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382189/change-language-for-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Comment: It won't fix your issue, but `atrLang.slice(atrLang.length -2)` can be just `atrLang.slice(-2)`. :-)

Comment: @ZakariaBenHmida thanks for your answer it works now it was just the files upload issue