# Jquery XDSoft Datetimepicker issue in Arabic Language

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

**Html**

```
   <input type="text" ID="txtDate"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#txtDate').datetimepicker({             
                mask: true,
                timepicker: false,
                format: 'd M Y',
                lang:'ar'
            });           
        });
 </script>
```

I am using Xdsoft datetime picker.

In English Language and Arabic Language, the Calender is displaying properly.

**My issue is:**

In English, it is displaying the selected Date in textbox properly as:
02 Nov 2015

But, In Arabic, it is displaying the selected Date in textbox as:
02 Nov 2015

I want the nov value in Arabic.

Please help guys!

Reference: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382189/change-language-for-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: its not Date time picker. Its jQuery Date Picker.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker):

> !!! The latest version of the options 'lang' obsolete. The language setting is now global. !!!
>
> Use this:
>
> `$.datetimepicker.setLocale('en');`

So your setup code would need to change to:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.datetimepicker.setLocale('ar');
        $('#txtDate').datetimepicker({             
            mask: true,
            timepicker: false,
            format: 'd M Y',
            lang:'ar'
        });           
    });
```