# How to change language on bootstrap 4 datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-4

I've been stuck on changing the language of a calendar from `English` which is the default to `French` on `Bootstrap 4` and I can't do it, it's driving me mad!

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrapdatepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
<script src="./js/main.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date_input = $('input[name="date"]');
    var container = $('.input-group').length > 0 ? $('.input-group').parent() :
        'body';
    var options = {
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
        weekStart: [1]
    };
    date_input.datepicker(options);
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the link to the package datepicker ? So we can help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change language for bootstrap DateTimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382189/change-language-for-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Answer (score 4):

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.fr.min.js"></script>`

Use this tag after bootstrap-datepicker. and this

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
      language: 'fr'})
```

It will work.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you haven't passed the language key to options.

Try adding this keys as options:

```
 var options = {
    language: 'fr'
};
```

All locales are available under `js/locales`. Be sure to include it after plugin initialization.

References:
1- https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/i18n.html
2- https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#language
3- [Change language for bootstrap DateTimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382189/change-language-for-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Comment: Thanks very much, Mehi I really appreciate. I've tried this 2 days ago and now but it doesn't work for me! It's really driving me mad!

Comment: Can you tell me what you tried? did you add language to options? can give a code sandbox or git repo?

Comment: the form is on index.html end the button is on menu nav top-right "se faire rappler" https://hafid-good.github.io/aro/index.html thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use translation i18n of lang and call it, theres no needed to call language specific. Like this.

```
this.$i18n.t("fixed_pickups.weekdays.monday") }
```