# How to change the language of the datepicker to spanish

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datepicker

So far i have, this code, the idea is change the language from english to spanish

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4', iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome', language: 'es', format: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382189/change-language-for-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change language for bootstrap DateTimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382189/change-language-for-bootstrap-datetimepicker)